# igraph: error message from get.adjacency: not a graph object

Tags: r, igraph

I am doing this. I keep getting the same error over and over. Thanks in advance.

```
library(igraph)
library(sand)

zoo=read.csv("C:\\Documents and Settings\\kkk\\Desktop\\moo.data",header=FALSE)

a<-get.adjacency(moo)
**Error in get.adjacency(zoo) : Not a graph object**

V(moo)
**Error in V(moo) : Not a graph object**
```

**EDIT** Further info from comments

I am running the following commands and get the following error.

```
library(igraph) 
library(igraphdata) 
library(sand) 

zoo=read.csv("C:\\Documents and Settings\\kkk\\Desktop\\zoo.data",header=FALSE) 
a <- get.adjacency(zoo) 
# Error in get.adjacency(zoo) : Not a graph object 

vcount(zoo)
# Error in vcount(zoo) : Not a graph object
```

How do i know what are the graph objects which support the zoo data

**DATA**

The first`20 rows` of dataset `zoo`. (Full data available from [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/zoo/zoo.data) with a description [here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/zoo/zoo.names))

```
zoo <- structure(list(V1 = c("aardvark", "antelope", "bass", "bear", 
"boar", "buffalo", "calf", "carp", "catfish", "cavy", "cheetah", 
"chicken", "chub", "clam", "crab", "crayfish", "crow", "deer", 
"dogfish", "dolphin"), V2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V3 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), V4 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), V5 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), V6 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), V7 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), V8 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), 
    V9 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V10 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), V11 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), V12 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), V13 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), V14 = c(4L, 4L, 0L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 
    0L, 0L), V15 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V16 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), V17 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V18 = c(1L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    2L, 1L, 4L, 1L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", 
"V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", 
"V16", "V17", "V18"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. Give us an example of the dataset, and code that actually runs? "moo" doesn't exist.

Comment: look ar the help from `?get.adjacency`, the first argument to be passed to the function is a `graph` object, but you are passing a `data.frame` (i guess).

Comment: hello that data set is zoo. To re-iterate the question. i am loading the data from 
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/zoo/zoo.data. i am running the below cmds and see the following error.
library(igraph)
library(igraphdata)
library(sand)

zoo=read.csv("C:\\Documents and Settings\\kkk\\Desktop\\zoo.data",header=FALSE)

a<-get.adjacency(zoo)
**Error in get.adjacency(zoo) : Not a graph object**
> vcount(zoo)
Error in vcount(zoo) : Not a graph object

how do i know what are the graph objects which support the zoo data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link to the data. I have edited your question - can you check that it is a fair representation. cheers.

Comment: Well the issue is that you have just passed a dataframe to `get.adjacency` (as suggested in my comment above). You need to create a graph object from the data. Perhaps you need to learn the structure from the data and then pass this to `get.adjacency`.

Comment: can you tell me how to create a graph object and pass that to get.adjacency? Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't make much sense. What do the columns represent? An adjacency matrix would have the same number of rows and columns to let you know which nodes are connected. It's unclear how you want to turn this raw data into a graph.

Comment: Hi user20650, can you tell me what command you used to change the format of the table to the format you gave me zoo <- structure(list(V1 = c("aardvark", "antelope", "bass", "bear", 
"boar", "buffalo", "calf", "carp", "catfish", "cavy", "cheetah", 
"chicken", "chub", "clam", "crab", "crayfish", "crow", "deer", 
"dogfish", "dolphin"), V2 =

Comment: `dput(zoo)` for the full data (although for obove I just used the first 20 rows , hance `dput(zoo[1:20, ])`

Comment: You can read about igraph graph objects here: http://igraph.org/r/doc/aaa-igraph-package.html What are the columns in your data set? How is you network defined?

Comment: Hi Gabor,how do i add a graph object for this and how to call dataframe for the created graph object.
These are the column names in the dataset..Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", 
"V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", 
"V16", "V17", "V18")

Answer (score 7):

Your question is rather vague so this is a bit of a guess at what you are trying to accomplish.  You seem to be trying to create an adjacency matrix from a graph, but you have neither. So in your case you have to create the adjacency matrix first, and then create the graph from that.

The file you link to is a csv file containing attribute data about 101 animals (in the rows). In addition to the animal's name there are 17 attributes (in the columns). Generally, an element is 1 if the animal has that attribute, 0 otherwise. There are two exceptions to this which complicate matters a bit: column 14 has the number of legs, and column 18 has the animal "class", an integer between 1 an 7. In a sense both of these are categorical variables. The main point is that this is *not* a graph object.

Assuming you want to think about this as a graph, and that the animals (rows) will be the vertices, an adjacency matrix is a square matrix (101 X 101 in this case), wherein each element `[i,j]` identifies how "strongly connected" animal `i` is to animal `j`.

An adjacency matrix is a special case of a similarity matrix, wherein each element `[i,j]` is a metric that captures how "similar" row `i` is to row `j`. To create one we first need to define "similarity". There are many ways to do this. The one I have chosen is to simply count the number of attributes that animals `i` and `j` have in common. This corresponds to the number of columns in `zoo` where `zoo[i,col]==zoo[j,col]`, excluding columns where both rows contain 0. Fortunately in R this is very easy using the `dist(...)` function in the `proxy` package.

```
url <- "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/zoo/zoo.data"
zoo <- read.csv(url,header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(proxy)
sim   <- function(x,y) sum(x==y) - sum(x==0 & y==0)
adj.M <- as.matrix(dist(zoo[-c(1,18)],method=sim))
adj.M[1:5,1:5]
#   1 2 3 4 5
# 1 0 7 3 8 8
# 2 7 0 3 7 8
# 3 3 3 0 3 4
# 4 8 7 3 0 8
# 5 8 8 4 8 0
```

So animals 1 and 2 have a similarity score of 7, which means that there have 7 attributes in common. Animals 1 and 3 have a score of 3, meaning they have 3 attributes in common, etc.

The function `sim(x,y)` is defined to calculate the similarity between two rows, and the function `dist(...)` applies this function to every combination of rows in `zoo`, excluding columns 1 and 18. We exclude column 1 because it has the names, and column 18 because it has the "class" which presumably is derived from the information in the other columns.

If all you want is the adjacency matrix, you could stop here, without ever resorting to `igraph`. If you want to take advantage of the functionality in `igraph` to analyze and visualize the relationship between animals, then you have to create an `igraph` object.

```
# colnames(adj.M) <- zoo[[1]]   # uncomment to display animal names in plot
g <- graph.adjacency(adj.M, weighted=TRUE, mode="undirected")
```

So `g` is an undirected graph with edge weights drawn from the adjacency matrix. Now we can, as an example only, calculate the community structure of `g` based on the edge weights.

```
communities <- leading.eigenvector.community(g)
groups      <- membership(communities)
# do groups map to animal "class" from data?
by(zoo[c(1,18)],groups,print)
```

This basically groups the animals so that animals in a given group are more highly connected (larger edge weights) to other animals in the same group than to animals in other groups. By examining the output of the last line above, you can see that this approach successfully put all animals from `class=1` into group 1, and generally puts animals from class 4, 5, and 7 in group 2, and animals from class 2, 3, and 6 in group 3.

As an example of using `igraph` for visualization, we make a new graph with just the first 20 animals, calculate community structure as above, and plot the graph with vertices color coded based on group. The Fruchterman-Reingold layout tries to place the vertices so that vertices with higher edge weights are closer together.

```
sub.g       <- induced.subgraph(g,V(g)[1:20])   # just the first 20 animals
communities <- leading.eigenvector.community(sub.g)
groups      <- membership(communities)
set.seed(1)   # for reproducible layout
plot(sub.g, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold(sub.g,weights=E(sub.g)$weight),
     vertex.color=groups+1)
```

[image]

Clearly to take advantage of this you need to know or learn at least a little bit about graph theory. At the very least, you should read the documentation on `?graph.adjacency`, `?communities`, and `?layout`.